# Finding the Eigenvectors/Eigenvalues of an unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

Let $L$ be a line that goes through the origin and the point $(-4,3)$.

Additionally, let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that for any vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the vector $Av$ is given by the reflection of $v$ about the line $L$.

Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ without determining $A$ explicitly.

Not really sure how to go on about this.

We have a line, a point, and a matrix. $Av$ is the reflection of $v$ about the line $L$. I can imagine $A$ being $\{e_2,e_1\}$, but apparently we should do it without figuring $A$ out?

Also, not really sure what the purpose of the given point is, so I'm overall pretty confused about this.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The vector $v=(3,4)$ is perpendicular to the line so its reflection gives $Av=-v$.

But also for $u=(-4,3)$ you have $Au=u$ in the reflection process, then the Eigen-values are $-1$ and $1$ with the corresponding $v$ and $u$ as Eigen- vectors.

Comment: Thank you, a few questions: 1) How did you figure $3,4$ is perpendicular to the line, and how is $Av = -v$ if that is the case? 2) I don't quite understand $Au = u$, why would u be in there, how can you know this without knowing $A$? Sorry, still super confused, if you have a minute could you make this more noob friendly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vector $(3,4)$ is perpendicular to $(-4,3)$ because their inner product is zero. If you draw both vector you can see how the angle between them is 90 degrees. The reflection $Av$ based on the line changes the sign of $v$, you can think this as if the line thru $u$ is like a mirror. And finally $Au=u$ because being in the mirror nothing happens within the reflection to $u$.